Issue with automatically update images using Flask, AJAX in html
I need to automatically update the images in every 10 seconds on web interface. But my current codes only update the images one time after initiate the program, otherwise I have to refresh or press the "GO" button ( button for send an text to client side) to update them. I am a beginner of the Flask and JavaScript, so I need some help to figure it out that what is the reason for that.
This is the output received in terminal, after run the app.py.
This is the output received in terminal, after run the app.py.(without submit a text)
I tried these codes and AJAX for auto update using created JSON file.
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, jsonify
import cv2
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

rgb = None
depth = None
instructions = []

def capture_image():
    global rgb, depth
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, rgb = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite('Web Interface/static/rgb.png', rgb)
    ret, depth = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite('Web Interface/static/depth.png', depth)
    cap.release()

@app.route("/")
def vln_org():
    status = "waiting.."
    return render_template('vln.html', status=status, instructions=instructions)

@app.route('/vln', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def vln():
    global rgb, depth, instructions
    if request.method == "POST":
        status = "READY"
        # getting input with name = instr in HTML template
        instruction = request.form.get("instr")
        instructions.append(instruction)
        print("The instruction is: " + instruction)
        #return "The instruction is: " + instruction
        return render_template("vln.html", status=status, instructions=instructions)
    else:
        status = "success"
        print(status)
        capture_image()
        return jsonify({'status': status, 'rgb_image': url_for('static', filename='rgb.png'), 'depth_image': url_for('static', filename='depth.png')})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    capture_image()
    app.run(debug=True)

Use an AJAX call and use jquery;
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  function updateImages() {
    $.get("/vln", function(data, status){
      if (status == 'success') {
        // Update the images
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        $('img[src$="rgb.png"]').attr('src', '{{ url_for("static", filename="rgb.png") }}?ver=' + currentTime);
        $('img[src$="depth.png"]').attr('src', '{{ url_for("static", filename="depth.png") }}?ver=' + currentTime);
        $('#status').text(data.status);
        // Check the status
        if (data.status == 'done') {
           //Stop sending GET requests
           clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {
          // Schedule the next update
          setTimeout(updateImages, 10000);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  var intervalId = setInterval(updateImages, 10000);
  updateImages(); // Call the function immediately to update the images on initial load
});
</script>


